# java - spreading out objects on a line evenly

Tags: java, object, line

I am creating objects on a line in a window created by this piece of code:

```
void createTurtles() {
     int nrTurtles = Keyboard.nextInt("Set amount of turtles: ");
     w = new GraphicsWindow(500, 300);
     drawLinez();
     for (int k = 1; k <= nrTurtles; k++) {
        Turtle t = new Turtle(w, 50, 50 + k*10);
        t.right(90);
        t.setSpeed(100);
        t.penDown();
        turtles.add(t);
     }
}
```

This codeline:

```
        Turtle t = new Turtle(w, 50, 50 + k*10);
```

Creates one turtle at the time. Right now i have set that the turtles will have the Y coordinat of 50, and the X coordinat of 50+k*10. This is because the line starts at the X coordinat of 50 and stops at the X coordinat of 250.

Now what i want is, based on the nr of turtles created (user inputs this), i want the turtles to be spread on this line evenly. How to do it? It has do to with the line that i wrote and maybe the k value or the 10.

The line is illustrated in the picture (see link below), its the red line, that the number of turtles are created at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devide the `height - 100` of the window by the number of turtles and you will have your `distanceBetweenTurles`:

```
int nrTurtles = Keyboard.nextInt("Set amount of turtles: ");

int height = 300;
w = new GraphicsWindow(500, height);

drawLinez();

double distanceBetweenTurles = (height - 100.0) / nrTurtles;

for (int k = 1; k <= nrTurtles; k++) {
    Turtle t = new Turtle(w, 50, 50 + (int) (k * distanceBetweenTurtles));
    t.right(90);
    t.setSpeed(100);
    t.penDown();
    turtles.add(t);
}
```